# C#, Оптимизация кода, задать нужное количество параметров для метода

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Имею такую задачу: проходиться по коллекции файлов, и проводить фильтр по определённым условиям. Причём условия формируются непосредственно перед проходом по всем файлам.
Выглядит сейчас это примерно так:

```
 foreach (string f in FileList.MainList)
 {
     // max размер подходит?
     if (max_size != 0)
         continue;

     // min размер подходит?
     if (min_size != 0)
         continue ;

     // Имя файла 
     if (filenameYES!=null || filenameNO!=null)
         continue;

     // Имя папки  
     if (pathnameYES != null || pathnameNO != null)
         continue;
 }
```

`max_size, min_size, filenameYES, filenameNO` и другие условия определяются ДО прохода по всем файлам. Для того чтобы ускорить выполнение кода, мне как-то нужно вывести проход по всем файлам в отдельный метод, и вызывать этот метод уже только с теми условиями, которые определены. То есть чтобы в каждом файле программа не думала какие условия заданы, а сразу проверяла только заданные условия. Просьба подсказать как сие осуществить

Comment: Есть несколько условий, например
1. Максимальный размер файла
2. Минимальный размер файла
3. Имя файла содержит букву А

Есть код, итогом которого должно стать понимание, какое из каждого из этих условий должно проверяться в цикле, а какое нет. 
После этого идём в цикле по всем файлам и проверяем файлы только на те условия, которые, как определили ранее, должны проверяться. 

Зачем это нужно - условий много, файлов много. Нужно чтобы проверились именно ненулевые, назовём их так, условия дабы ускорить процесс обработки

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее всего отделить логику фильтрации от логики обхода.

Вынесите создание предиката, обслуживающего выбор файла, в отдельный метод. Будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
Func<FileInfo, bool> CreateFilter()
{
    List<Func<FileInfo, bool>> conditions = new List<Func<FileInfo, bool>>();
    var r = new Random(); // нужен только для примера
    if (r.Next(2) == 0) // при каком-то условии
        conditions.Add(fi => fi.Length > 15); // добавляем фильтр на мин. длину
    if (r.Next(2) == 0) // при ещё каком-то условии
        conditions.Add(fi => fi.Length < 100000); // добавляем фильтр на макс. длину
    if (r.Next(3) == 2) // при ещё каком-то условии
        conditions.Add(fi => fi.Name.StartsWith("x")); // добавляем фильтр на имя файла
    if (r.Next(4) == 0) // при ещё каком-то условии
        conditions.Add(fi => fi.Extension == ".exe"); // добавляем фильтр на расширение
    // комбинируем все условия в один фильтр
    return fi => conditions.All(c => c(fi));
}
```

И пользуемся:

```
var filter = CreateFilter();
var fileInfos = files.Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).Where(filter);
foreach (FileInfo fi in fileInfos)
{
    // обрабатываем файл
}
```

---

Можно было бы в принципе ускорить выполнение фильтров, перейдя к `Expression`'ам, но выгода от этого всё равно нивелируется временем доступа к файловой системе.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать несколько методов, которые на вход будут принимать MainList.
Сначала в главном методе ты проверяешь условия и в зависимости от условия ты вызываешь нужный метод в котором уже проверять условия не требуется.